# Google Speech API not returning valid JSON

Tags: google-speech-api

I am currently receiving invalid JSON such as the following:

> results {
>     alternatives {
>       transcript: " Brooklyn Bridge"
>     }
>     stability: 0.01
>   }

This is using the example code found here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/cloud-client

I'd like to be able to parse the result, but I'm not sure how to.

Is there a way to force the result to return valid JSON or perhaps a way to parse the result?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the result isn't JSON, it's a [Google Protobuf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) object.  It looks like you've pasted the string representation of the object.  You should be able to access the fields of this object directly.

[This example from Google](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/grpc/transcribe_streaming.py#L180) might help clear it up.

Try something like this and see if it works:

```
for result in your_response_from_google.results:
    print(result)
```

Based on your example, I think you're looking at a [`StreamingRecognizeResponse`](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1beta1#google.cloud.speech.v1beta1.StreamingRecognizeResponse) object.